# How to call another python script within a script?

Tags: python

I am a Noob in Python. I am using a script which is downloading html pages. There are two file in my project. File 1 & File 2.
I need to execute File 1 to start downloading. after 20/30 second it stops and shows a message "Too many requests, click File 2 script to renew IP". Then i need to click/execute File 2 script. It changes IP within 1 second. Then I need to click the File 1 script again to start the same process (downloading). It works so on manually.

Now I want to automate the process. I want to execute the File 2 automatically right after the message shows in the console ""Too many requests, click File 2 script to renew IP". Then it will automatically execute File 1 again to continue the process so on. So that i don't need to touch the eclipse anymore.

Here is a part of code.

```
if the_page.find("Too many requests")>=0:
    print "Too many requests"
    print "Rclick File 2 script to renew IP"
    fout = open(self.dir+"/limit.txt",'wb')
    limits = str(count)+","+str(upper)
    fout.write(limits)
    fout.close()
    break
```

Actually i need a automatic way to do this job scheduling.
Where should I put the new code ? what will be the code please ?

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the source code, you can wrap the functionality in file 2 into a class or simply a function.

Then you can import file 2 into file 1 like importing other python modules. That will let you call the function from file 2 rather than running the script.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

You can execute it like a regular external command with os.system or subprocess. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-run-external-command-and-get-output/